# Rename all files in directory by adding filesize to it by bat

Tags: batch-file

I want to rename all files in directory by adding filesize to it by batch file. e.g apple.bmp of size 66kb changes to apple[66KB].bmp. this is the code i am trying

> ```
> > SET count=1 SET foldersize=0 FOR /f "tokens=*" %%F IN ('dir /s/b
> > %folder%') DO (call :calcAccSize "%%F") echo %filesize% GOTO :eof
> > 
> > :calcAccSize  REM echo %count%:%1  REM set /a count+=1  set /a
> > foldersize+=%~z1
> > 
> > ren %1 %~nx1[%~z1].mp4  GOTO :eof
> > 
> > @pause
> ```

**[edit /]**

Assumed actual code:

```sh
SET count=1
SET foldersize=0
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%F IN ('dir /s/b %folder%') DO (
    call :calcAccSize "%%F"
)
echo %filesize%
GOTO :eof

:calcAccSize
REM echo %count%:%1
REM set /a count+=1
set /a foldersize+=%~z1

ren %1 %~nx1[%~z1].mp4
GOTO :eof

@pause
```

Comment: `@for %%f in (*) do @ren "%%~f" "%%~nf[%%~zfKB]%%~xf"`

Comment: Well, the code you posted does not attempt to do what you ask for; did you just copy it from somewhere? Please read [mcve]…

Answer (score 0):

The following batch file renames all files in current directory with appending `[xKB]` left to file extension, except

- the batch file itself on being also in the current directory and
- the files containing already `[xKB]` in their file name.

The code is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /V "\[[0123456789][0123456789]*KB\]"') do if not "%%~fI" == "%~f0" (
    set /A FileSizeKB=%%~zI / 1024
    set "NameFile=%%I"
    if not "%%~nI" == "" (
        set "FileName=%%~nI"
        set "FileExt=%%~xI"
    ) else (
        set "FileName=%%I"
        set "FileExt="
    ) 
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    ren "!NameFile!" "!FileName![!FileSizeKB!KB]!FileExt!"
    endlocal
)
endlocal
```

The files can contain a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` in their file name. The code renames also files correct starting with a dot and having nor more dot, i.e. a file with name like `.Test File!`.

The arithmetic expression works only for files with a file size smaller than 2.147.483.648 bytes, i.e. less than 2 GiB because of the Windows command processor `cmd.exe` supports only arithmetic expressions by using 32-bit signed integers with a value range of −2147483648 to 2147483647 (−2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>−1).

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~f0` ... batch file name with full path.
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul` and `|`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal characters when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with redirecting the output file names list to `findstr` with using a separate command process started in background using `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line within `'` appended as additional arguments.